# Change the 'actual' in custom matcher

Tags: rspec

So I've created a custom matcher (see [here to see why I'm not using redirects_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24479071/setting-http-status-codes)):

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :redirect_to_location do |expected|

    match do |actual|
        expected == actual.location.gsub('http://test.host/', '')
    end

    failure_message_for_should do |actual|
        "should redirect to #{expected}, instead redirected to #{actual}"
    end

    failure_message_for_should_not do |actual|
        "should not redirect to #{expected}, but did redirect to #{actual}"
    end

    description do
        "should redirect to #{expected}"
    end
end
```

I utilise it like this in my specs:

```
it { should redirect_to_location "browse/#{folder.id}" }
```

While it works, its failure messages don't:

```
should redirect to browse/1, instead redirected to #<ActionController::TestResponse:0x007fe039930848>
```

This should read as:

```
should redirect to browse/1, instead redirected to bowser/3
```

How do I update `actual` to be what's returned by `actual.location.gsub('http://test.host/', '')` inside the custom matcher?

Answer (score 1):

Using an instance variable seems to work:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define :redirect_to_location do |expected|


    match do |actual|
        @actual = actual.location.gsub('http://test.host', '')
        expected == @actual
    end

    failure_message_for_should do |actual|
        "should redirect to #{expected}, instead redirected to #{@actual}"
    end

    failure_message_for_should_not do |actual|
        "should not redirect to #{expected}, but did redirect to #{@actual}"
    end

    description do
        "should redirect to #{expected}"
    end
end
```

Not sure if it's the correct way to do it though.

Comment: Instance variables work and seem right in matchers written from scratch, so I'd think they'd be the way to go when using `define`.